# Kotlin Android studios inflater crash issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

So am working on a project and I am having significant trouble with the recyclerview and cardview right now I am not getting any errors from the code but it keeps crashing and I have no idea why

```
**class MyAdapter(private val myDataset: ArrayList<Results>) :**
RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

class MyViewHolder(val cardView: CardView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(cardView) {
    val userName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {
  **val aCardView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false) as CardView**
    return MyViewHolder(aCardView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.userName.text = myDataset[position].userName

}

override fun getItemCount() = myDataset.size
}
```

The Logcat only points at the ** lines but there's nothing really there, any ideas?
       S orry it took so long it was being picky about what I could and 
       couldn't post, I hope this gives more detail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/card"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="172dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="172dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
                android:text="This will be the name"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="240dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="240dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: why are you typecasting your view to cardview, you can simply access it from your view. if you cant then just share your xml.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: add your xml code.

Comment: Got it all, any ideas?

Comment: are you done with updating again and again xml code?

Comment: yes sorry I didn't realize it wasn't posting it all and for a while it wouldn't let me post it at all

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) Synthetics to refer view or findView method.
Layout inflater inflate layout not a view/ widget, so dont type cast just make a reference using layout view.

```
class MyAdapter(private val myDataset: ArrayList<Results>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val userName = itemView.name
        //val userNames = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.userName.text = myDataset[position].userName

    }

    override fun getItemCount() = myDataset.size
}
```

Comment: Same issue, it still gives me the error with the correction

Comment: you didnt copy the code, as the error is for something else. Please copy and paste same code and inflate the correct layout and add logs in question not in answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
2020-03-16 14:47:11.159 26375-26375/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.githubmobile, PID: 26375
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    at com.example.githubmobile.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.kt:19)
    at com.example.githubmobile.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.kt:10)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21927)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21927)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:148)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:43)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1892)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:918)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21927)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21927)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21927)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21927)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21927)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:779)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21927)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3080)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2590)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
2020-03-16 14:47:11.160 26375-26375/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```